# How do each of the damage types differ?

Tags: wars-of-the-roses

I know the game has different damage types, Piercing, Bludgeoning, and Slashing, but I'm uncertain how each of them differ.

How do each of the damage types differ from each other?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know exactly. From game play, piercing (back end of a warhammer or bill, stabbing) seems to be better against heavy armour, slashing (swords) not so much. No idea about blunt, I always use the one side of the warhammer.

Historically, in reality, older (before the scope of the game) "cutting" swords would be more like chiseled than sharp, hack and hack and hack, not slash really. The armour was so heavy and the steel so poor (vikings describe "fixing" their blades by using their feet to bend them back to shape) that cutting was useless. Warhammers and many blunt weapons became the weapons of knights on foot to fight other knights, swords generally would not cut it, no pun intended. Shorter versions were also used as backups for cav.

So, long story short, in theory blunt or bludgeoning damage should be good against armour as well, because it actually kind skips the armour to knock around it's contents, like a Yorkist pig.